# Cannot ask Question

Tags: support, post-ban

I was told to either make positive contributions or edit bad questions to get the question ban lifted. I deemed the bad questions unworthy of a second chance as they were literally garbage so I turned towards positive contributions. I assumed this to be along the lines of having your answer accepted but I have had a couple of my answers accepted to no avail. Am I not having enough positive contributions still or am I still going to have to have my bad questions edited?

Do I *need* to fix my bad questions, or can positive contributions alone lift my ban?

Comment: @davidism I am actually asking how do you know if those contributions are actually counting

Comment: Positive contributions also involve getting upvotes (though the accepts aren't hurting). We don't know the formula, nor how far in the hole you are. Keep contributing, and it will lift.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET so I can get the ban lifted by answering questions alone or at some point am I required to go back and fix bad questions

Comment: @FeatheredOrcian I can't tell you for sure, because the algorithm is a secret. From reading Meta, my *understanding* is that positive contributions alone can get you out. Fixing the bad questions is *really* helpful because it makes the hole itself smaller.

Comment: Your deleted questions also count against you (in as far as their votes still count against you). You have a number of negatively voted deleted questions.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET thank you you could post that as an answer and I would accept it.

Comment: Read the post linked to you by davidism, and the info you were provided when you were banned! From the post: "*users who don't do the most basic kinds of research themselves*". "To avoid bypassing the filter its internal rules are a secret" - "What can I do to release the ban? - Before you do anything else, fix your existing posts! ..." It's full of info.

Comment: @James you dont understand what this question is asking as well as bradelydotnet

Comment: Yes, I do. I'm referring to your extended questions you posted as comments. All that, including what you asked Bradley to post in an answer, is already duped in the other post.

Comment: @James oh sorry I skimmed that post lack of effort on my part I should be more Atentive in the future but I did get my answer in the end

Comment: I mean no offence at all, but perhaps that attitude is part of why you are banned in the first place? You need to spend a little time getting to know what is and what isn't allowed on the sites, as well as doing some reading and research yourself. It's goes a long way with other users when you have at least made an effort, rather than want them to do it for you. As for your initial question, I agree it isn't clear if you are making progress, but that of course is intentional, as if that info was public then everyone would game the system and lift their bans in no time with minimal effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to getting accepted answers, "positive contributions" take into account how many upvotes your posts are receiving as well.

They *are* taking an effect, but because we don't know the algorithm, or how far into the hole you have gotten, we can't say how much you need to do for the ban to lift.

As far as I know, positive contributions alone *can* lift the ban, but fixing your bad posts is doubly useful, because it shrinks the hole you are in (removes the negative votes) and counts as a contribution (because you get positive ones).